# exception occurred processing JSP page /jsp/CreateEmp.jsp at line 19

Tags: spring

when I change the form tag then these errors occurring :

```
    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:522)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

    root cause:

    java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?    org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:86)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:81)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:197)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:76)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.CreateEmp_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(CreateEmp_jsp.java:117)
org.apache.jsp.jsp.CreateEmp_jsp._jspService(CreateEmp_jsp.java:81)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
rg.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:337)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
```

Comment: actually the error is at line no 19,can anyone solve this?

Comment: There's definitely more error messages than this. Post everything.

Comment: you are right there are few more error occured.